# Does linux cksum command value varies on different system?

Tags: linux

If i do "cksum filename" in two different linux system with different hardware spec, i am getting different checksum value for the same file. 
Can anyone tell me the reason behind this?

The "filename" is a binary file generated in one system and copied to other system.

Comment: How did you copy this file? Is the size the same?

Comment: scp to the destination system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm employed by `cksum` is specified by POSIX.  All POSIX-compliant systems (including GNU/Linux) should compute the same value for the same file -- that's the whole point.  If you get different values on different systems, then either the program is buggy or the files (at least `cksum`'s view of them) are not, in fact, the same.  I wouldn't bet on the program being buggy.

Do note, however, that there are likely to be other hashing and checksumming programs on both systems (e.g. `md5sum` or `sum`).  The sums computed by each of these programs are likely to differ, but each should be consistent from system to system.  They could be a useful alternative for you, and/or they could give you a second opinion of whether the files really are the same.